# Onkeydown JS function to add an input that calls the same function

Tags: javascript, html, function, increment, keycode

I'm working on a form and am trying to create an `onkeydown` function that does the following:

1. Only fires when the *tab key* is pressed (got this working ok)
2. Inserts a new element (`input`) (got this working ok)
3. Then the inserted `input` calls the same `onkeydown` function (stuck here!)

Tried Increment ++ but not working?

Here's where I'm up to:

```
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type ="text" OnKeydown = "tab(event)" />
        <div id ="insert">

        </div>
    </form>


</body>


<script>
    function tab(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 9) {
            var ins = '<input  type ="text" OnKeydown = "tab(event)"/>'; 
            document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML=ins;
            ins++;
        }
    };
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use event HTML attributes. Use event listeners in JS. Use event delegation. Consider using jQuery if any of what I've just typed sounds unfamiliar.

Comment: `ins++` is invalid, as you can add a number to an HTML object. --- As for examples, I recommend using google using the terms I have listed. --- Reading is your best friend here.

Comment: Simple example: use `addEventListener` on the `form` element. Listen to the `keydown` event. Check if the `event.target` is an `input` of type `text`. If so, call a function which duplicates the `input` element.

Comment: @user3464091 Are you looking to `append` **new** inputs every time the `tab` key is pressed? EG: focus first `input`, press `tab` key, new `input` is created and focused, press `tab` key again, new `input` is created and focused, etc. etc. I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/0r26bv28/) to simulate the process.

Comment: Yes, I want to eventually create a row with the last `input` calling the same `function` that adds a new row / input...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points of interest are:

- attach an event handler with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)
- start your code on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
- use [input autofocus attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)
- use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to insert a newly created element to DOM

```js
function tab(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    // remove the event listener for the old element
    event.target.removeEventListener('keydown', tab);
    
    
    var ins = document.createElement("input");
    ins.type = "text";
    ins.autofocus = true;
    document.getElementById("insert").appendChild(ins);
    ins.addEventListener('keydown', tab, false);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener('keydown', tab, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input type ="text"/>
    <div id ="insert">
    </div>
</form>
```

In order to add a row of inputs like described in the comment you have to create and append a new row to the table, create 3 cells and for each one add the corresponding input field and set the tab event  handler for instance on the last cell.

To create a new row in a table you can refer to [insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow), while in order to add new cells you can take a look to [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

```js
function tab(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    event.target.removeEventListener('keydown', tab);

    var table = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    var ins = document.createElement("input");
    ins.type = "number";
    ins.autofocus = true;
    newCell.appendChild(ins);

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    ins = document.createElement("input");
    ins.type = "text";
    ins.autofocus = true;
    newCell.appendChild(ins);

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    ins = document.createElement("input");
    ins.type = "number";
    ins.autofocus = true;
    newCell.appendChild(ins);

    ins.addEventListener('keydown', tab, false);
    setTimeout(function () {
      ins.focus();
    }, 10);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener('keydown', tab, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text"/>

    <div id="insert">
        <table id="tbl">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Text</th>
                <th>Number</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaetanoM that works great! The only issue is you click to a previous `input` the function keeps being called when tab is pressed. Also, if I wanted to insert a row of `inputs` where would I put the `html`?

Comment: Perfect! @gaetanoM I'll be adding various `inputs` to the row so the html will look something like `<tr><td><input type="number" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="number" /></td></tr>`

Comment: @user3464091 Thanks so much.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @gaetanoM I can figure it out from here!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
    <form>
    <input type ="text" OnKeydown = "tab(event)" />
    <div id ="insert">

    </div>
    </form>


</body>


<script>
function tab(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 9)
        {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.setAttribute("OnKeydown","tab(event)");
       // var ins = '<input  type ="text" OnKeydown = "tab(event)"/>'; 
       var div= document.getElementById("insert")
        div.appendChild(input);
        }

};


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution but same issue...click back and function keeps firing!

Answer (score 0):

```js
   document.onkeydown = function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                 //left arrow
                 alert('left arrow pressed');
                 break;
            case 38:
                 //up arrow
                 alert('up arrow pressed');
                 break;
            case 39:
                 //right arrow
                 alert('right arrow pressed');
                 break;
             case 40:
                 var createfield = 
                 '<br><input type="text" name= "abc[]"><br>';
                 document.getElementById('inputFields').innerHTML += createfield;  
                    break;
              default:
              //get keycode by using e.keyCode
                 alert(e.keyCode);
                 break;
            }
        };
```

```html
    <body>
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">

            <div><input type="text" name="abc[]"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="inputFields"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).